# Java: Math.pow() is returning zero

Tags: java, int, double, long-integer, pow

I'm triyng to compute the avarage of the average and variance of a given set of numbers. The average seems to work well, but I can't compute the variance, the result is always 0. I'm pretty sure I have some mess with variables type:

```
 int numRuns = 5;

    ArrayList<Long> numbersOfIOs = new ArrayList<Long>();
.
.
.

  long averageNumberOfIOs = 0;
  for(Long io : numbersOfIOs){
        averageNumberOfIOs+=io;
  }

  System.out.println("Average number of I/Os: " 
                     + (averageNumberOfIOs/numRuns) 
                     + " I/Os");

long varianceNumberOfIOs = 0;

for(Long io : numbersOfIOs){
     double temp = Math.pow(2.0,(double)(io-averageNumberOfIOs));
     varianceNumberOfIOs+=Math.round(Math.pow(2,(io-averageNumberOfIOs)));
}

System.out.println("Variance: " + (varianceNumberOfIOs/numRuns) + " I/Os\n");
```

I placed temp there just for debug purpose, I found it to be always 0.

any help will be aprreciated

Comment: what are you passing into Math.pow each iteration? I would log the two values going into Math.pow and temp each iteration

Comment: Have you printed `temp` on each iteration? What do you get?

Comment: debug and check what is the value of io-averageNumberOfIOs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

First. The variable `averageNumberOfIOs` contains the sum of IOs, not the average. 
Second. To compute a square of a variable `x`, use `Math.pow(x, 2.0)`, not `Math.pow(2.0, x)` as you did in the code.

Once you fix the above two problems, you will get the correct result.

The reason why you got 0 is this. Because `averageNumberOfIOs` contains the sum of IOs, the expression `(io-averageNumberOfIOs)` is a negative number (which is probably big negative numbers), regardless of the value of `io`. Computing `Math.pow(2.0, (io-averageNumberOfIOs))` means that you compute 2 to the power of big negative number, which produces a value very close to 0. Summing this over IOs, you still get 0.

Comment: yes that was the problem. I misunderstood the documentation :(

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`averageNumberOfIOs` is the sum of all your `io` so `averageNumberOfIOs > io`.

Therefore `io-averageNumberOfIOs < 0` and `0 < Math.pow(2,(io-averageNumberOfIOs)) << 1`.

So when rouding, you get `varianceNumberOfIOs == 0`.

Hence `varianceNumberOfIOs/numRuns` is equal to 0.

Comment: ok, that was a stupid error. 

so now I changed `averageNumberofIos` to be the actual average:
`averageNumberOfIOs=averageNumberOfIOs/numRuns;`

but `temp` is still =0.0

Answer (score 1):

Several problems in this code:

1) for calculating the variance you should sum up `square of (x - average)`. You don't use the average but the sum of the values.

2) instead of the square of the quantity you calculate 2 to the power of the quantity. The arguments of `Math.pow` are exchanged.

3) the call to `Math.round` ruins the result. The variance is a real number.